# Is there an auto-trace tool/feature in a vector application other than Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, lettering

I'm looking for an alternative to Illustrator that I can use for the occasional auto-tracing task. My application is vectorizing hand lettering.

I want an alternative to Illustrator with this feature because I don't use it enough to pay for it monthly. ..but I'm happy to pay for it on a one-time basis.

Comment: VectorRaster --> https://www.lostminds.com/vectoraster7/

Comment: corelDraw x8 maybe best alternative

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is a free and open source "professional vector graphics editor for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux", and has a "Trace Bitmap" feature that should do what you need.

[Inkscape tutorial: Tracing bitmaps](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html)

[image]

[image]